# Windows 10 taskbar icons not combining

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

I am using windows 10, and in taskbar properties "Taskbar buttons" is set to "Always combine, hide labels".

However I noticed that Visual Studio Code and WebStorm 10.0 ignore this rule. Labels are hidden, but icons are not combined and this bothers me a lot.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Other icons combine as excepted? What have you attempted to resolve this?

Comment: Yes. Well I've tried googling for error but couldn't find anyone with similar problem.

Comment: You might try a trick from Windows 7 for the same problem; with the ones giving you trouble open, right click on the taskbar icon and pin them to the taskbar. Then go back and unpin them. Worth a try...

Comment: Yeah, I just found out, that this was possible in windows 7, but in Windows 10, when I right click on the program, I only got an option to unpin it..

Comment: What happens when you unpin it?

Comment: Well, shortcut disapears, and icon for opened program stays as long you keep it open. When I close it, there are no more icons for this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer...

This seems to be a bug in some applications on Windows 10.
VisualStudio Code fixed it in their 0.8.0 insiders preview. https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/Detail/18603

You might want to switch to insiders version of Visual Studio Code, in my opinion it is as good as the stable version: https://www.instant.ly/s/Y5nt1/nav#p/186a0

For WebStorm I do not have a solution, maybe someone else might have one.

Comment: As I do not have enough reputation: The bug in WebStorm/Idea is already tracked: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143209

Comment: I think other apps may also fail and that is app-dependent. Nothing to do with Windows 10 config. I also observed that Sublime Text 3 can combine the pinned icon with active windows while Chrome cannot.